# Flutter square_in_app_payments app will not run on simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, square

I'm trying to install the square sdk into my flutter app and I am having an issue running on ios simulator. I get an error message and the app terminates before installing on simulator. The installation stalls in VSCode.

This is my podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.1'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      # Force CocoaPods targets to always build for x86_64
      config.build_settings['ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'x86_64'
    end
  end
end
```

About my system setup:

```
macbook air M1 2020
os: Ventura 13.3.1
ios simulator:16.4
Xcode version : 14.3
```

Error that I get when trying to run on ios simulator:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: DYLD 1 Library missing
Library not loaded: @rpath/ThreeDS_SDK.framework/ThreeDS_SDK
Referenced from: <EAF8E1BA-E3AE-372F-B629-A255114E419B> /Users/juliapak/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/63D54239-A58D-4E24-8D89-901EA6209734/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/C6630B21-CF36-4CEA-897F-10128AF7D448/Runner.app/Frameworks/SquareBuyerVerificationSDK.framework/SquareBuyerVerificationSDK
Reason: tried: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/ThreeDS_SDK.framework/ThreeDS_SDK' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/ThreeDS_SDK.framework/ThreeDS_SDK' (no such file, no dyld cache), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/ThreeDS_SDK.framework/ThreeDS_SDK' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/ThreeDS_SDK.framework/ThreeDS_SDK' (no such file, no dyld cache), '/Appl
(terminated at launch; ignore backtrace)
```

Comment: We have exactly this problem! It's working fine on Android but on iOS, no chance. 1.7.5 works without issue! Do you have any developments on this?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options and both about same activity.
You need to add or check **XCode -> Runner -> Build Phases -> Run Script** (it could be multiple).

One of them should contains:

```
    # Type a script or drag a script file from your workspace to insert its path.
FRAMEWORKS="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}"
"${FRAMEWORKS}/SquareBuyerVerificationSDK.framework/setup"
```

or

```
# Type a script or drag a script file from your workspace to insert its path.
    FRAMEWORKS="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}"
    "${FRAMEWORKS}/SquareBuyerVerificationSDK.framework/ThreeDSSDKResources.bundle/setup"
```

If no such script then create it with + at the top left corner in xcode